# Is It Possible to Build To iOS 5 Devices from XCode 4.1 or 4.0.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

XCode 4.2/iOS 5 SDK has broken some frameworks that I depend on to support external MIDI hardware accessories in my app.  My app that I built with 4.0.2 works fine on my iPhone 4 running iOS 5 when installed from the store, so I uninstalled XCode 4.2 and downgraded to XCode 4.0.2.  But now I can't build to my iOS 5 devices -- the Organizer says the version is unsupported.  Is there some way to trick XCode 4.0.2 or 4.1 into building onto a device running 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode 4.2 and make sure that the iOS4 SDK is installed, then set the "Base SDK" build property to that version. I'm pretty sure that building iOS5 apps with Xcode 4.1/4.0 is going to be a world of pain.

Comment: When I install XCode 4.2 with the iOS 4.3 SDK installed and without installing iOS 5, it acts like there's no iOS SDK installed at all so I can't build for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you can compile and debug on iOS 5 devices even using XCode 3.2. You won't have iOS 5 simulator though.  <--  doesn't work with iPhone 4S

Comment: How? This didn't work for me, it tells me the version of iOS is unsupported and won't build to it.

Comment: @PaulSlocum Same here. Try to disregard this warning and your app will  popup on your iOS 5  phone. It won't work with iPhone 4s because Xcode 3.2 doesn't know how to retrieve its symbols and gets stuck.